# Create Dictionary inside other Dictionary from raw JSON

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I had this in JSON:

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "age": "99",
    "gender": "male"
}
```

and I serialize it with (using Dictionary<>):

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>();
    dictionary.Add("name"  ,"name1");
    dictionary.Add("age"   , "99");
    dictionary.Add("gender", "male");
```

and now... How do i serialize this??

```
{
    "id1"   : { "value": "11" },
    "id2"   : { "value": "22" },
    "Date"  : { "value": "2021-11-11" },
    "id3"   : { "value": "44" },
    "id4"   : { "value": "55" },
    "id5"   : { "value": "66" },
    "id6"   : { "value": "77" },
    "others": [
                  {
                      "er1" : { "value": "111" },
                      "er2" : { "value": "222" },
                      "er3" : { "value": "333" },
                      "er4" : { "value":   444 },     <---This is a integer
                      "er5" : { "value": "555" }
                  }
              ]
}
```

I have tried to put a variable of type Dictionary<> inside another of the same type without success...

Comment: Are the `id1` ... `id6`, `others`, `Date` and `er1` ... `er6` always going to be the same?  Are the types of all the `value`s always going to be string except `Date` and `er4`?

Comment: They will not always be the same data types, because they come from a dimanic table (like a excel). The data is received by a server and before (POST/PUT) it was sent as x-www-form-urlencoded but now it is required to make it generic (build it on the fly)

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that the answers to the questions I asked in the comments are "Yes" (it's always good to look at the comments you get), here's a possible solution:

Starting at the bottom, this represents all those "value"/value pairs:

```
public class ValueJson<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This class represents the items in the "others" collection - note that they all use a `string`, except for "er4", which is an `int`:

```
public class OthersJson
{
    [JsonProperty("er1")]
    public ValueJson<string> Er1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("er2")]
    public ValueJson<string> Er2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("er3")]
    public ValueJson<string> Er3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("er4")]
    public ValueJson<int> Er4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("er5")]
    public ValueJson<string> Er5 { get; set; }

}
```

Then, putting it all together, a class to represent the overall JSON:

```
public class NestedJson
{
    [JsonProperty("id1")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id2")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id2 { get; set; }

    public ValueJson<DateTime> Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id3")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id4")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id5")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id6")]
    public ValueJson<string> Id6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("others")]
    public List<OthersJson> Others { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the JSON you have in the question (transformed into a C# string):

```
private const string TheJson = @"{
            ""id1""   : { ""value"": ""11"" },
            ""id2""   : { ""value"": ""22"" },
            ""Date""  : { ""value"": ""2021-11-11"" },
            ""id3""   : { ""value"": ""44"" },
            ""id4""   : { ""value"": ""55"" },
            ""id5""   : { ""value"": ""66"" },
            ""id6""   : { ""value"": ""77"" },
            ""others"": [
                          {
                              ""er1"" : { ""value"": ""111"" },
                              ""er2"" : { ""value"": ""222"" },
                              ""er3"" : { ""value"": ""333"" },
                              ""er4"" : { ""value"":   444 },     // <---This is a integer
                              ""er5"" : { ""value"": ""555"" }
                          }
                      ]
        }";
```

and finally some code to deserialize that JSON:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NestedJson>(TheJson);
```

If you don't have any constraints on the names or types, and you just want to use a `Dictionary`, you will likely have to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`